# Fetch using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I'm trying to use fetch() to simulate getting some data from ./Network.ts and doesn't work. I get this in console:

```
Response {type: "basic", url: "csb.app/[object%20Promise]", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true…}
```

My component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { getOrders} from "./network";

export const Component: React.FC = () => {
  const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState({});
  
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchResults();
  },[]);
  const fetchResults = async() => {
    try {
      const data = await fetch(getOrders());
      setSearchResults(data);
    } catch (e) {
      return console.log(e);
    }
  };
  return (
    <table className="table table-striped table-hover">
      <thead className="thead-dark">
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">ID</th>
          <th scope="col">Name</th>
          <th scope="col">Amount</th>
          <th scope="col">ETA</th>
          <th scope="col">Status</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

<tbody>{console.log(searchResults)}</tbody>
    </table>
  );
};
```

Network.ts

```
interface Delivery {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  amount: number;
  status: string;
  eta?: number;
}

export const getOrders = (): Promise<Order[]> => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const data = [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "Order 1",
          amount: 3,
          status: "active",
          eta: 15
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: "Order 2",
          amount: 5,
          status: "pending"
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          name: "Order 3",
          amount: 3,
          status: "active",
          eta: 10
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          name: "Order 4",
          amount: 4,
          status: "upcoming"
        },
        {
          id: 5,
          name: "Order 5",
          amount: 3,
          status: "active",
          eta: 25
        },
        {
          id: 6,
          name: "Order 6",
          amount: 3,
          status: "active",
          eta: 5
        }
      ];

      resolve(data);
    }, 1000);
  });
};
```

Also, I need them to render them by status and eta ascendant.
Status should be sorted in the following order: active, upcoming, pending.

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: You don't have a `getDeliveries` function.

Comment: @Andy I modified the code, is this how is supposed to be? Now I'm getting in console Response {type: "basic", url: "https://csb.app/[object%20Promise]", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true…}

Comment: @Christian10 Check the first code example. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: @3limin4t0r I've modified now the code, forgot to rename getDeliveries to getOrders. Is the functions from Network.ts

Comment: @Dilshan I've put also ```const response = data.json();``` and ```setSearchResults(response);``` and now I'm getting a pending promise in console

Comment: `fetch(getOrders())` doesn't make sense. `getOrders` already returns the data. Only use `await getOrders()`, nothing else. `fetch` expects an url as the argument, not a promise.

Comment: @Bergi You are right. I wasn't aware that I'm not using an URL. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm trying to use fetch() to simulate getting some data

Well you shouldn't. What you're doing in `getOrders` is using *`setTimeout`* to simulate getting some data asynchronously. That's fine - but you don't need `fetch` for that! You use `fetch` only when *really* making a network request to get data, not for simulation. So just drop it from your code and it'll work:

```
const fetchResults = async() => {
  try {
    const data = await getOrders();
//               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    setSearchResults(data);
  } catch (e) {
    return console.log(e);
  }
};
```

When you want to get rid of the simulation, you should change only the `getOrders` implementation and put the `fetch()` call *inside* there, replacing the `new Promise((resolve) => {…})` stuff.